# Reactjs: Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded when trying to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

I am trying to do a simple thing:
check if a parameter is on the URL and then set a state for my component. This state will determine if some html code should be displayed or not.

Basically this dummy sample may give you an idea of what I have:

```
class Lalala extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {showStatement : false}

    }
    parseURLParams(urlParams) {
        if (urlParams.indexOf('blabla')> -1) {
          this.setState({
            showStatement: true
          })
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { location } = this.prop
        this.parseURLParams(location.search);
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, every time it renders, it calls the parseURLParams function which tries to set the state, and, of course, when the setState is called, the render function is being called again, causing a infinite loop which ends up returning this error in the console.

Could you guys tell me a better way to set this state? once this is something that doesn't depend on an event, I am a bit confused.

Thanks

Comment: You've created an infinite loop-- you're not allowed to `setState` in your `render` method, but you are effectively doing that by calling a function that sets state.  There are only a few react lifecycle hooks in which state setting is non-problematic.

Comment: Check out the [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) -- you probably want something like `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: You should have a look at [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) which takes care of passing props from the current location to components defined for that route.

Comment: @trixn I am using react-router to get the url params already.. then I parse it to check for specific params and, if it's there, I needed to change the state.. and here comes the problem..

Comment: You don't need to parse url parameters yourself. react-router can do that for you if you defined your route correctly. [See the documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params). The params will be in the `match` prop passed to your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cause you using setState in `render`. It willbe render -> setState -> render-> setState -> render... You should move `this.parseURLParams(location.search);` to other lifecycle like this

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(JSON.stringify(nextProps.location) !== JSON.stringify(this.props.location)){
    this.parseURLParams(this.props.location.search);
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if you reload the `.../?blabla` page, as `componentWillReceiveProps` won't fire.

Comment: Ya. Just add the `componentWillMount` and put the `this.parseURLParams(this.props.location.search)`

Comment: which is exactly why using a wrapper component is much less error prone..

Answer (score 1):

Try setting state in a different lifecycle hook, like `componentDidUpdate`.  Also, if the prop value you want is available at the initial render, you'll want to set it in state there as well:

```
class Lalala extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showStatement : false,
            showBrokerStatements: props.location && props.location.search && props.location.search.indexOf('blabla')> -1
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.parseURLParams(this.props.location.search);
    }
    parseURLParams(urlParams) {
        if (urlParams.indexOf('blabla')> -1) {
          this.setState({
            showBrokerStatements: true
          })
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { location } = this.prop
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems that it doesn't run the parseURLParams function when doing this.. I added some console.logs but nothing happens

Comment: @Periback Is `location` available on `props` at the initial render?  If so, you should just be setting it in the constructor as well.  I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Although I already accepted Giang's answer, I also tried yours now and it would also work! Thanks man!